# Smack lost connection while message proccessing

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, slack-api

I have the following problem

```
//The XMPP server sent 100 messages
ChatManager.getInstanceFor( connection ).addChatListener( new ChatManagerListener() {

        @Override
        public void chatCreated( Chat chat, boolean b ) {

            chat.addMessageListener( ( Chat chat1, Message message ) -> {

                // some slow processing, and on processing message number 75 the client is shutdown.                     

            } );

        }
    } );
```

25 messages are lost. For they were delivered to client, but have not yet been processed.

Is there any way to notify the XMPP Server manually, on receiving these messages?

Comment: do message processing task in background thread and enable ping to keep alive your connection.